# HTML5 input form - display span only if error or pattern not matched

Tags: css, html, validation

Would like to handle input form errors using HTML5 and CSS - without JS.

Currently, I have span that is set to invisible, until the input is valid. However, the default state of the input text field is blank, thus invalid, and the span is visible by default.

HTML:

```
 <input class="form-control" placeholder="#####" 
 name="zip" pattern="\d{5}"  title="Enter valid 5 digit zip" 
 required><span class="formhelp">5 digit ZIP required</span>
```

CSS:

```
.formhelp
   display:none;
   font-size: 70%;

input:invalid + .formhelp
   display:block;
```

The objective is to only display the span if the pattern is invalid after the field loses focus, but not empty as is the default state.

Comment: I don’t think this is possible – CSS has no way to differentiate between those two states.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible Using CSS only even with the pseudo selector `empty` :

```
input:not(:empty):not(:focus):invalid
```

because until now CSS has no (pseudo) selectors for  value(s) so the empty pseudo class will never select anything in a proper HTML document.

Comment: How's that different from what he has now?

Answer (score 0):

As stated by [CBroe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29224072/html5-input-form-display-span-only-if-error-or-pattern-not-matched#comment46656883_29224072) CSS doesn't know how to differenciate both states.

Even though, [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/vufdnk1x/1/) is JSFiddle with the css that you're looking for, but It DOES NOT update the state, (tldr, for css its always valid or invalid, no midpoints).

```
input:invalid:not([value=""]) + .formhelp{
    display:block;
}
```